# Routing with angular ui router - Bookmark feature

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-routing

I have a controller and a view.View contains three drop down's and table. All the drop down's are dynamic, once the dropdown1 is selected based the value selected REST call is made to fetch dropdown2 values,controller contains calls to fetch required details.

[image]
Once all the drop down's have been selected.On click of search the table would be populated with the values.URL should be changed and table should be populated with the values.

When user bookmarks the URL uses and next time when the URL is opened all the drop down's and table should be populated automatically.

URL - http://localhost:8080/sample/#/home?dropdown1=abc&dropdown2=xyz&dropdown2=value

I am not getting idea how to achieve this Is there anyway to achieve this using angular UI router based on certain condition?

Answer (score 0):

Add parameters to your state

```
$stateProvider
    .state('app.home', {
        url: '/home?dropdown1&dropdown2&dropdown3'
        // ...
    });
```

and, for initing model, in controller check `$stateParams`, like:

```
$scope.dropdown1 = $stateParams.dropdown1 || null;
$scope.dropdown2 = $stateParams.dropdown2 || null;
$scope.dropdown3 = $stateParams.dropdown3 || null;
```

Comment: thanks. I have a doubt. As I mentioned values are populated dynamically,REST call to retrieve the values for dropdown2 will be based on value selected in dropdown1 and so on. If I do this, will the REST calls happen and application behaves as usual when user copies URL in a different tab?

Comment: Try to fill you lists based on value from some local variable.
There is no difference, you can choose a value manually or from local variable.